# Show half data in one column and other half in other column

Tags: php, css, laravel

I'm working with Laravel.

I have this view:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
     <h2>Selecciona al cliente que pertenece el proyecto</h2>
      @foreach ($clients as $key => $client)
          <div class="radio">
                  <label>
                      <input type="radio" name="client" value="{{$client->name}}">
                        {{$client->name}}
                  </label>
          </div>
      @endforeach
</div>
```

How can i do it to print the variable, in two divs like here?

```
<div class="col-md-6">Here</div>
<div class="col-md-6">Here the second half</div>
```

Thanks!

I want the two divs with class="col-md-6" inside the div with class="col-md-12" and in left show 1/2 of the data, and in the right show the other 1/2.

**SOLVED**

More easy than i think it..

```
<div class="col-md-12">
     <h2>Selecciona al cliente que pertenece el proyecto</h2>
      @foreach ($clients as $key => $client)
          <div class="radio">
                  <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label><input type="radio" name="client" value="{{$client->name}}">{{$client->name}}</label>
                  </div>
          </div>
      @endforeach
```

Hope helps someone!

Comment: Where do you want to place the `div` with `class="col-md-3"` ?

Comment: Let me edit the question :) I will explain it better

Comment: where you print variable in class ?

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd I don't understand too much your question, you print the variable with {{$client->name}}

Comment: @HariHarken edited!

Comment: so, if I understand this correctly, you want to print _HALF_ of the name in one col, and the other  _HALF_ in the other?

Comment: Please rephrase your question its not clear what you want to achieve

Comment: @LluísPuigFerrer Do you mean $clients half data display in one div and other half data display in second div?

Comment: @Simplicity yes!

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd yes!

Comment: @Digitlimit show HALF of the name in one col, and other HALF in other :)

Comment: It's solved :)!

Answer (score 1):

You try:

```
$counter = 0;
<h2>Selecciona al cliente que pertenece el proyecto</h2>
@foreach ($clients as $key => $client)
@if(counter == 0 || counter % 2 == 0){
echo '<div class="col-md-12">';
   }
   <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="radio">
         <label>
         <input type="radio" name="client" value="{{$client->name}}">
         {{$client->name}}
         </label>
      </div>
      @if(counter == 0 || counter % 2 == 0){
 echo ' </div>';
   }
   $counter ++;
</div>
@endforeach
```

> I do not do php, maybe the syntax will not be correct, but you take a
>   look at my ideas